# Angular 2 Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute on formArrays Facing an error while using Reactive Forms approach

Tags: angular

I am trying to iterate over a formArray in my component and then fill the input boxes upon clicking a update button but I get the following error while running :-

**Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute**

Here is what the logic looks like on my class file

***recipe-edit.component.ts***

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
recipeform:FormGroup
id:number
editmode=false
constructor(private router:Router,private 
route:ActivatedRoute,private reservice:Recipeservice) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params)=>{
    this.id=+params['id']
    this.editmode=true
    this.initform()
  }
  )
 }

private initform(){

let recipeingredients=new FormArray([])


if(this.editmode){
  const recipe=this.reservice.getrecipe(this.id)

  if(recipe.ingredients!=null){
  for(let ingredient of recipe.ingredients){
  recipeingredients.push(
  new FormGroup({
  'name':new FormControl(ingredient.name),
  'amount':new FormControl(ingredient.amount)
   })
   )
   }
  }
  }
  this.recipeform=new FormGroup({

 'ingredients':recipeingredients
})
}



onsubmit(){
console.log(this.recipeform)
}






 }
```

Here is what the logic looks like on my html file
***recipe-edit.component.html***

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
<form [formGroup]="recipeform" (ngSubmit)="onsubmit()">


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" formArraynName="ingredients">
      <div
        class="row"
        *ngFor="let ingredientctrl of 
 recipeform.get('ingredients').controls;let i=index"
        [formGroupName]="'i'"

        style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
           formControlName="name"
            >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input
            type="number"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="amount"
           >
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: at least you have a typo: `formArraynName="ingredients"`

Comment: @AJT_82 oh thnks but it didnt worked though !

Comment: Okay, could you create a stackblitz for this? :)

Comment: I see another error... `[formGroupName]="'i'"` should be `[formGroupName]="i"`